# Importing third-party scripts in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have built a Next JS application and on one of my pages I am trying to display a ResDiary Javascript bookings widget.

This loads perfectly the first time the page is rendered. However if I navigate away to another page and then back again the widget no longer loads.

I am trying to implement this using the newer onReady property on the Script tag (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/script#onready).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Script from 'next/script';

export default function Book() {
  const [scriptLoaded, setScriptLoaded] = useState(false);

};
return (
    <>
     {scriptLoaded && (
        <div id="rd-widget-frame" style={{ maxWidth: '600px', margin: 'auto' }}></div>
     )}
     <input id="rdwidgeturl" name="rdwidgeturl" value="https://booking.resdiary.com/widget/Standard/xxxxxx/xxxxxx?includeJquery=false" type="hidden" />
       
     <Script
        src="https://booking.resdiary.com/bundles/WidgetV2Loader.js"
        strategy="beforeInteractive"
        onReady={() => {
          console.log('Script has loaded')
          setScriptLoaded(true);
       }}
     />
   </>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you're using this in a client component add `"use client"` at the top.
Also, you're closing the function before the return statement in this code.